# Page cannibalising ranking?

Tags: google, search-results, google-ads

My site [glueckundsegen.de](https://glueckundsegen.de) is seeing declining rankings and I wonder whether the following might be a reason for that and whether there is something that can be done to resolve that.

The keyword I'm speaking of is "stammbuch" which is kind of a registry book for official marriage documents.

There is a dynamic AdWords ad which performs pretty well and its landing page is automatically chosen to be `/blog/in-4-schritten-zu-deinem-perfekten-stammbuch` which is not the page that should (and currently is) ranking highest. I guess due to this campaign this "unwanted" landing page is ranking too for the keyword ("stammbuch").

Most of the time these two pages: the one I want to rank (`/stammbuch`) and the one I do not want to rank (`/blog/in-4-schritten-zu-deinem-perfekten-stammbuch`) appear directly after each other.

I wonder whether this might be a problem, because the unwanted result of course steals clicks from the wanted result?

If so, any ideas what to do about it?

An obvious solution would be to stop the dynamic ad campaign, but I don't want to do that since it has a phenomenal conversion rate.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Google search results]

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! I do not know Adwords at all. I would think you should be able to specify which page your ad points to. Is that possible? As far as ranting, that is a complex issue with lots of factors we can discuss. However, it appears to me your best answer would be found in Adwords.

Comment: What exactly are you searching for? If I simply search for `stammbuch` then I only see your first "wanted" result at #6 on the first page of Google search results. The second result does not appear at all for me... in the first 10 pages of Google SERPs. (Although I can't see how this could be the _cause_ of "declining rankings" anyway?)

Comment: @DocRoot: Yes I'm searching for stammbuch. It doesn't happen all the time, but the image above is a screenshot. My thought is that google is showing to hits for one site is a sign that it can't decide which one is the right one.